# How can I insert the button on a specific page using php wordpress using this code

Tags: php, wordpress

```
  add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'my_extra_button_on_product_page', 30 );

  function my_extra_button_on_product_page() {
  global $product;
  echo '<a href="URL">Extra Button</a>';
  }
```

how will I add this as a function on a specific page help me out with this

Comment: Are you trying to add the action to a page, or just the `my_extra_button_on_product_page()` function? Is this in the dashboard or while editing the theme?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this within a theme template (such as page.php) as:

`<?php do_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary'); ?>`

or in the Dashboard by using a Shortcode block in the Gutenberg page editor. You will first need to create the shortcode in functions.php.

```
function your_shortcode($atts, $content = null) {
      ob_start();
      add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'my_extra_button_on_product_page', 30 );
      return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode('shortcode_name', 'your_shortcode');
```

Then the shortcode would be `[shortcode_name]`